# Subtitles in QuickTime X

Tags: video, quicktime, subtitle

For ages I've been happily using QuickTime 7 Pro for all my video needs.  I guess with Catalina now the time has come to move on ...

But there is one thing that keeps holding me back. 
In QT7 I could easily add and remove subtitle files as simple text files in this form:

```
{QTtext}{timescale:100}{size:12}{backColor:0,0,0}{textColor:65535,65535,65535}{width:320}{justify:left}
[00:00:00.980]
{textEncoding:256}Hello!
[00:00:01.980]
[00:00:02.422]
{textEncoding:256}How are you?
[00:00:03.422]
```

etc.

That doesn't (didn't?) work in QuickTime X. Nor do I seem to be able to add SRT files to a movie file.

Now, I've heard some rumors that QuickTime X in Catalina is getting some Pro features.  Has anyone got a clue if any form of subtitles is finally supported or if there are any workarounds?
Much appreciated.